# How can I generate a random double within 2 intervals using java.util Random class?

Tags: java, double, intervals, random

I want to be able to generate a random double from 2 intervals, ie intervals are 0,1 and 5,8 would generate a single double between 0, 1, 5, 6, 7, and 8.

Ideally this would be possible using variables for the intervals and not rely on a known value.  I have tried applying the logic behind generating an int between multiple intervals, but can't make the two compatible.  Any tips?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried and what you are confused about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this would be the best way of doing it, but here is my initial approach to this problem:

We need to evaluate the total span of the bounds that we want. In your example, we need [0,1]U[5,8]. From `1 - 0 = 1`, and `8 - 5 = 3`. The total span is `1 + 3 = 4`.

Then I would generate a random number between the start of the first interval (`0`) and the start of the first interval + the total span (`0 + 4 = 4`). So, a random double between 0 and 4.

Let's say it's 0.5. It is less than the ending of our first bound ([0,1]), so this is our final number.

Now let's say our generated number was 2. It is greater than the ending of our first bound. We need to subtract the ending of the first bound from our generated number. `2 - 1 = 1`. Now we need to add the start of the second bound ([5,8]) to this number, so `1 + 5 = 6`. So `6` is our final number.

Here is the implementation:

```
public class RandomIntervals {
    static class Interval {
        double start;
        double end;

        public Interval(double start, double end) {
            this.start = start;
            this.end = end;
        }

        public double getSpan() {
            return end - start;
        }
    }

    public static double nextDouble(double min, double max) {
        return min + (max - min) * new Random().nextDouble();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Interval interval1 = new Interval(0, 1);
        Interval interval2 = new Interval(5, 8);

        double totalSpan = interval1.getSpan() + interval2.getSpan();

        double randomNumber = nextDouble(interval1.start, interval1.start + totalSpan);

        if (randomNumber > interval1.end) {
            randomNumber -= interval1.end;
            randomNumber = interval2.start + randomNumber;
        }

        System.out.println(randomNumber);

    }
}
```

Comment: Just realised I didn't account for intervals that don't start at zero. I'm editing this answer to cover that.

Answer (score -1):

Since Math.random in Java generates a number with approximately a uniform distribution, this problem is essentially generating a random on one larger interval and mapping it to two different intervals based on the value. Say the first interval is (a, b) and the second interval is (c, d), where c > b.

First, generate a random number between (a, b + d - c) or (0, b + d - c - a).

In the first case (a, b + d - c):

If the number is less than b, return the number. It is a random number from interval (a, b).

If not, return the number + c - b. It is a random number from interval (c, d).

In the second case  (0, b + d - c - a):

If the number is less than b - a, return a + number.

Else, return c + number + a - b, with the same reasoning as the first case.